# Why is TreeSet declared TreeSet<E> instead of TreeSet<E extends Comparable<E>>

Tags: java, generics, treeset

I was working with `TreeSet` and found a `ClassCastException` while calling `TreeSet#add()` method.

**Code:**

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Testing> ts = new TreeSet<>();
        ts.add(new Testing());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Testing cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at Testing.main(Testing.java:13)
```

Clearly it's because `TreeSet` is an **ordered collection** and it needs `Comparable` objects for ordering them, so why not declare its type as

```
public class TreeSet<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

and do the checking during compile time instead of throwing exception at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `TreeSet`'s element doesn't have to implement `Comparable`, since you can pass a `Comparator` to one of `TreeSet`'s constructors in order to impose an ordering for elements that don't implement `Comparable` (or for elements that do implement `Comparable` when you want to use an ordering other than the natural ordering defined by `Comparable`).

Comment: I guess I asked too fast without going through the whole API document... Thanks...:)

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in other answers, `TreeSet` keys could be not `Comparable` if custom `Comparator` is specified. It still would be possible to enforce compile-time check for your case. Suppose that we make the default constructor private and provide a static factory method instead:

```
public class TreeSet<E> {
    private TreeSet() {...}

    public static <E extend Comparable<? super E>> TreeSet<E> newSet() {
        return new TreeSet<>();
    }
}
```

This way you would be forced to use `TreeSet.newSet()` and compile-time type checking would fail if you assign it to `TreeSet<Testing>` and `Testing` is not comparable. Why it was not done? Because generics appeared in Java 1.5 only, while `TreeSet` appeared in Java 1.2, is it was not an issue these times. Now we have to deal with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is implemented, you can order items that cannot decide for themselves if they should be ordered in a higher or lower spot than the "other" item.

Take a real life example: You have a beauty contest. If you ask one of the girls if she is more beautiful than the one next to her, she will say yes. You cannot put them in an order just by asking them. So you need somebody else to be responsible for the ordering, the Comparator.

This allows you to order items that don't have the possibility to compare themselves with another item.